# Reporting in TFS VS 2017

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, report

My team works in a 2 week timebox and they indicate how many hrs each PBI, Task, or Bug will take via effort (if PBI) and remaining effort (if Task), and both if a bug.

As they progress through the Sprint they update their hrs. to show progress of effort.

For example,  it's July 24 and John knows that updating a module will take 20 hrs. To complete and as he progresses through the Sprint he updates that number to 15, 10, 5, and then eventually 0. My goal is to show a report with that trail to verify that the 20 hrs. committed to the task was completed. I did some research and could not find much help, but perhaps I'm not stating my question right. Any advice regarding this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I recently [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57433828/4629442) about some of the reporting options available. Take a look at the answer and see if it helps you. My operation is on Azure DevOps services, not TFS '17, so it might not apply exactly.

Comment: Thank you for assistance. I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is more like a  time tracker and generated report to verify or reflect it.

We do not have this kind of build-in feature or report in TFS server. However, as a workaround, there is a number of applications/add-on out there that expose TFS time tracking/time sheet capability.

They offer different levels of integration with TFS depending on your specific workflows/requirements. They pick up your TFS data entries and provide dashboards for operational reports as well as API to get data loaded to your systems.

[image]

Some 3rd-party extension for your reference：

- [7pace time tracker](https://www.7pace.com/timetracker)
- [SSW Time Pro](https://sswtimepro.com/)

Comment: Thank you for assistance. I will research the recommended apps.